# store data by day and hour - powershell

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

Id like to be able to store, change, and retrieve data by day and hour using powershell.

For instance, I have a list of data from which I can extract the dayOfMonth, hour, max, active, average.
I would like to be able to stick the 3 latter values in an array indexed by day and hour.
The raw data might look like this: (the avg val wouldnt be there yet):

```
12/13/19,08:13:04,13,13
12/13/19,08:43:04,10,9
12/13/19,09:13:04,11,9
12/13/19,09:43:04,12,7
12/13/19,08:13:04,10,12
12/14/19,08:13:04,8,2
12/14/19,08:43:04,10,4
12/14/19,09:13:04,8,7
12/14/19,09:43:04,11,1
12/14/19,10:13:04,9,7
```

I wish to be able to store the maxChannel,maxActive, and average, for each hour of each day, so the data in the array would look like this:

```
day,hr,max,actv,avg
13,8,13,13,11
13,9,12,9,8
13,10,12,2,2
14,8,10,4,3
14,9,11,7,4
14,10,9,7,7
```

I tried to store it in a previously created array

$arrOut2 = @()  #summary data

like this(which needless to say didnt work):

## initialize each needed row

```
     ForEach ($line in $arrFile)
     {
        $arrLine = $line.split(",")     #create an array with each word in line its own element
        $Date=$arrLine[0]
        $Time=$arrLine[1]
        $ChanM=$arrLine[2]
        $ChanA=$arrLine[3]
        $DateA=$Date.Split("/")
        $Day=$DateA[1]
        $TimeA=$Time.Split(":")
        $Hour=[int]$TimeA[0]
        $arrOut2 += ,@[$Day][$Hour](0,0,0)
     }

     ForEach ($line in $arrFile)
     {
        $arrLine = $line.split(",")     #create an array with each word in line its own element
        $Date=$arrLine[0]
        $Time=$arrLine[1]
        $ChanM=$arrLine[2]
        $ChanA=$arrLine[3]
        $DateA=$Date.Split("/")
        $Day=$DateA[1]
        $TimeA=$Time.Split(":")
        $Hour=[int]$TimeA[0]

        IF (($Hour -ge 8) -And ($Hour -lt 17)) {
            $AvCnt=$AvCnt+1 #count Intervals for averaging
            $AvTot=$AvTot+$ChanA  #sum active channels for averaging
            $AvgActChan=$AvTot/$AvCnt
            IF($ChanC -GT $arrOut2[$Hour][0]){$arrOut2[$Hour][0]=$ChanC}  #grab max chanC frm current hr
            IF($ChanA -GT $arrOut2[$Hour][1]){$arrOut2[$Hour][0]=$ChanC} #grab max chan Actv frm curr hr
            $ArrOut2[$Day][$Hour][2]=$AvgActChan #grab curnt chan Avg Active from current hour
        }
}
```

As you can see in the first forloop, I am attempting to use day and hour as indices. Powershell just doesnt like that - at least in that format.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can accomplish this? I know I could keep track of the current day and hour, then process it in separate variables, then when I see the day or hour change, write those to a separate array, but the data is quite a bit messier than Ive represented in this example and that would make the whole thing quite messy, when processing it within an array would be so much cleaner.

Appreciate any suggestions
thanks

Comment: If it was a datetime property, it would simply be something like `get-childitem | sort-object lastwritetime`

Comment: I just noticed the data list was unformated so I took that opportunity to present instead, an example of the raw data list. JS - I dont see how that would work since that may sort the data but it wouldnt summarize it into hourly increments (the real data has 12 intervals/hour)   -thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would sort it this way:

```
$data = import-csv data.txt -header date,time,a,b
$data | sort date,time
```

Comment: Hi JS - Im not trying to sort it, Im trying to store and summarize it by hour. The real data is 12 intrvls/hr over several days - I did it the old messy way(keeping track of the data row counts, summing them, then writing the sum to a new array when the current interval hour changes, but it was very messy. If there is a way to do it, collecting cumulative data directly in the array, Id still like to know it for next time. thx